Read field data from Sharepoint using Python - Missing or None for many fields
Objective: reading values of fields (columns) from a sharepoint library.
Code is below. Printing "fields" shows all, but printing "item.properties' only shows some of the fields, many of them "None" (surely available on web).[![screenshot][1]][1]
Additional info: Stragely enough, this code works (i.e. showing all field values) on another library in the same sharepoint.
Thanks!
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

# Replace these variables with your SharePoint details
site_url = "https://xx.sharepoint.com/sites/xx"
username = "xx@xx"
password = r"xx"

# Authenticate and establish connection
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(site_url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
    ctx = ClientContext(site_url, ctx_auth)
    print("Connection established successfully.")
else:
    print("Authentication failed.")
# Specify the library name
library_name = "Reports"

# Get the library
library = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(library_name)
ctx.load(library)
ctx.execute_query()

# Get all fields (columns) of the library
fields = library.fields
ctx.load(fields)
ctx.execute_query()

# Display column details
print("Columns in the Library:")
print(fields) # --> OK, all fields are listed

# Access items in the library
items = library.items.paged(50)
ctx.load(items)
ctx.execute_query()

items[0].properties # --> shows some of the fields, many of them are "None"


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/pzIj0rBf.png


I found the problem and the solution. I post here for future users.
Key point: Fields/Columns in Sharepoint have their 'type', which can be:

Text-based fields (like Text, Note, Date Time): can be directly read using 'InternalName' of the field.
NON-text-based fields (like 'People or Group'): can be read indirectly (see example below, note that 'InternalName' is managed differently with a suffix of 'Id')

# continued from the code in my question
# this example try to get emails of the user

# get info about users listed on the sharepoint
users = ctx.web.site_users
ctx.load(users).execute_query()

user_emails = {user.properties['Id']: user.properties['Email'] for user in users}
# some fake users do not have email
user_emails[0] = None

# loop through fields and items (rows)
for field in fields:
    print('>>>',field, field.properties['TypeAsString'])
    column_name = field.properties['InternalName']

    # check type of the field and treat accordingly
    if field.properties['TypeAsString']=='User': # type of 'People or Group' is 'User'
        # if field is 'user' -> read email
        # correct 'InternalName' of the field
        column_name += 'Id'
        # get email
        for item in items:
            value = item.properties.get(column_name, "N/A")  # Fetch column value
            # convert to email
            value = user_emails[value if value else 0]
            # debug
            print(f"//{field.properties['Title']}:\n{value}")
    else:
        # if field is text -> read directly
        for item in items:
            value = item.properties.get(column_name, "N/A")  # Fetch column value
            print(f"//{field.properties['Title']}:\n{value}")
    print("-" * 30)

